# Remove specific pattern from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an example string of "*welcome to my home page (23) | Ayman*". I need to remove `(23)` from this string. Note, that `23` is used only as example and can have any value in this place.

I tried this code:

```
$str = preg_replace("\(d)/", " ", $str);
```

But, it is not working as expected.

Comment: try this: `"\(\d+\)"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the code:

```
$str =  "welcome to my home page (23) | Ayman";
echo preg_replace("/\(\d+\)/", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

`(\(\d+\))` will capture `(23)` ([see it in action](http://regex101.com/r/aD0lJ2)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$Value =  "welcome to my home page (23) | Ayman";
echo preg_replace("/\(\d+\)/", "", $Value );
```

Here follow instruction  for Pattern changes

```
/     Denotes the start of the pattern
-     Literal - character
\d+   A digit, 1 or more times
```